# Smoothing corners in mesh

Tags: modeling

Any modelling experts? I have a mesh that even with Object smoothing On and Normals Auto UV Off has sharp corners (circled green in attached). Is there anything I can do other than remodeling from scratch (was a purchased asset)

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add "Subdivision Surface" Modifier.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess not the same as right clicking choosing 'Subdivide'